# How to programmatically set a node field as empty?

Tags: 7, nodes

I have some nodes with the following fields:

- Title
- Body
- Image

I want to programmatically set the body field as empty.

This is the code I used.

```php
$this_node = node_load($nid);
$this_node->body = array();
node_save($this_node);
```

This code causes the following exception.

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '104418' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO {node} (nid, vid, type, language, title, uid, status, created, changed, comment, promote, sticky, tnid, translate, uuid) VALUES (placeholders and their values) in drupal_write_record() (line 7170 of /var/www/rotary.local/docroot/includes/common.inc).

How can I set an empty body field?

I don't want to use [`field_attach_update()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_update/7.x) for caching purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove the value from you field you should do like this before saving it:

```
$this_node->body[$this_node->language] = array();
```

Comment: After testing the code with your suggestion I found that it still gives the error. However I am able to save the node using `field_attach_update`. What could be causing this?

Comment: @DipakYadav - That seems very strange, what error do you get?

Comment: The error was being caused because of a whole lot different reason.

Answer (score -1):

To make body field empty you should implement hook_node_presave() and inside this, use-

```
   $node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = '';
```